How can I modify this block of code to detect columns of made up of 3 or more blue cubes (Unity)
So I currently have this block of code where it detects if a row of cubes have 3 or more red cubes that are next to each other. The play area the cubes will be occupying will be 5 cubes wide and 10-15 cubes high. The reason why is because I'm going to program the cubes to drop from the top of the play area similar to tetris blocks. Which is why I'm using code that casts a ray from a empty gameobject that goes from left to right and another empty gameobject that casts a ray going from right to left which are blocked by cubes that aren't red. Code works for horizontal checks because there are only 5 cubes to check. If I use the same method for checking columns I found that since columns will be roughly 10-15 cubes high there's a possible chance that there might be 3 or more blue cubes where the rays from both top and bottom sides are blocked by non blue cubes.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ColorMatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ScoreManager scoreManager;
    public LayerMask cubeLayer;
    public string cubeColor;
    public int detectedRedCubesLayer; // Layer for detected red cubes
    public int detectedBlueCubesLayer;
    public List<GameObject> detectedRedMatches = new List<GameObject>(); // List to store detected cubes
    public List<GameObject> detectedBlueMatches = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<List<GameObject>> detectedMatches;
    public Vector2 rayDirection;
    public Vector2 rayOrigin;
    public bool matchDetected;

    public void Start()
    {
        rayOrigin.x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;
        rayOrigin.y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        CheckForMatches();
        
    }

    private void CheckForMatches()
    {
        
        if (cubeColor == "Red")
        {

            if (matchDetected == false)
            {
                CheckHorizontalMatches(cubeColor);
            }
            else
            {
                DisableCubeMatches(cubeColor);
            }
            
        }
        
        if(cubeColor == "Blue")
        {
            CheckVerticalMatches(cubeColor);
            DisableCubeMatches(cubeColor);
        }
        
    }


    private void CheckHorizontalMatches(string color)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, rayDirection, Color.red);

        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {


            if (matchDetected == true)
                continue;


            // Perform the match checking
            var matches = CheckMatches(rayOrigin, color, rayDirection);

            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Found at least one match in row {row}!");
                matchDetected = true;
            }

            foreach (var matchList in matches)
            {
                // Add each matched GameObject to the detectedRedMatches list
                detectedRedMatches.AddRange(matchList);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckVerticalMatches(string color)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, rayDirection, Color.blue);
    }

    private void DisableCubeMatches(string cubecolor)
    {
        if (cubecolor == "Red")
        {
            // Implement logic for disabling consecutive red cubes
        
        }
        else if (cubecolor == "Blue")
        {
            // Implement logic for disabling consecutive blue cubes
        }
    }

    private List<List<GameObject>> CheckMatches(Vector2 rayOrigin, string color,Vector2 rayDirection)
    {
        

        // shoots a ray through all objects - results are ordered by distance from origin
        var hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(rayOrigin, rayDirection, Mathf.Infinity, cubeLayer);

        var matches = new List<List<GameObject>>(4); // There are maximum 4 matches in a column of 15 items
        var currentMatch = new List<GameObject>(15); // maximum match size would be 15 if an entire column is blue e.g.

        for (var i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
        {
            // Have we hit something we are looking for?
            if (hits[i].transform.CompareTag(color))
            {
                // simply track it in the current match list
                currentMatch.Add(hits[i].transform.gameObject);
            }
            else // we did hit something we are NOT looking for
            {
                // Does the currentMatch already contain enough items?
                if (currentMatch.Count >= 3)
                {
                    // if so we add a new match to the results and start a potential new one
                    matches.Add(currentMatch);
                    currentMatch = new List<GameObject>(15);
                }
                else
                {
                    // otherwise for a bit of memory saving we reuse the existing match
                    // but erase it to also start a new one as it didn't reach the required amount of items 
                    currentMatch.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        return matches;
    }
}


Note:Red blocks can only "match" horizontally while blue blocks can only "match" vertically
So far I'm satisfied with the horizonal bit of the code where it detects if there are 3 or more cubes that are of the color red since that there could only be a maximum of 5 red cubes that can be in a row. The real problem is detecting 3 or more blue cubes that are stacked on top of each other.

If I understand correctly your horizontal check would also not work currently if in a row there where cubes
b r r r b

as you are only detecting whether the first cubes to the right are red. Instead I would indeed suggest to raycast only in one direction and use RayCastAll as suggested by shingo.
=> So you only need to have one ray per row and one per column.
And then you just have to search for potential matches - here it depends a lot on your use case. For the blue ones if there can be up to 15 cubes in a column it is very much possible that there are multiple matches in the same column like e.g.
r
b
b
b
r
b
b
b
r
b
b
b
r
b
r

So I would probably use something like e.g.
private List<List<GameObject>> CheckMatches(Vector2 rayOrigin, string color, bool horizontal)
{
    var rayDirection = horizontal ? Vector2.right : Vector2.down;

    // shoots a ray through all objects - results are ordered by distance from origin
    var hits = Physics2D.RayCastAll(rayOrigin, rayDirection, Mathf.Infinity, cubeLayer);

    var matches = new List<List<GameObject>>(4); // There are maximum 4 matches in a column of 15 items
    var currentMatch = new List<GameObject>(15); // maximum match size would be 15 if an entire column is blue e.g.

    for(var i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
    { 
        // Have we hit something we are looking for?
        if(hits[i].transform.CompareTag(color))
        {
            // simply track it in the current match list
            currentMatch.Add(hits[i].transform.gameObject);
        }
        else // we did hit something we are NOT looking for
        {
            // Does the currentMatch already contain enough items?
            if(currentMatch.Count >= 3)
            {
                // if so we add a new match to the results and start a potential new one
                matches.Add(currentMatch);
                currentMatch = new List<GameObject>(15);
            }
            else
            {
                // otherwise for a bit of memory saving we reuse the existing match
                // but erase it to also start a new one as it didn't reach the required amount of items 
                currentMatch.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    // This covers for the case where the last item in hits is contained in the last/only match
    if(currentMatch.Count >= 3)
    {
        matches.Add(currentMatch);
    }

    return matches;
}

This gives you potentially multiple matches in a single row/column so you can then check and handle the results like e.g. (pseudo code as not knowing the rest of your code)
for(var column = 0; column < 5; column++)
{
    var matches = CheckMatches(columnRayPositions[column], "blue", false);
    
    if(matches.Count > 0) Debug.Log($"Found at least one match in column {column}!");
    
    foreach(var match in matches)
    {
        // do something with the match information
    }
}


Oh right I completely overlooked the possibility of two non-red cubes blocking the raycasts on both sides. Thanks for bring it up.
So assuming from the code you posted the program will cast a ray and then store the objects the ray collides with in a list? How does it determine if there are three or more cubes that connect based on the conditions where red only connects horizontally and blue only connects vertically

@PlacidoPenitente if by "the code" you mean RayCastAll it returns an array of all objects hit by the ray. The CheckMatches returns list of matches where each match is a list of the connected objects. As the hits array is in order it basically just goes through them and checks for connected objects with the given tag => Providing the correct origin positions and ray directions and tag accordingly is up to you ;) You will basically call the blue cube checks with color: "blue", horizontal: false and the red cubes with color: "red", horizontal: true

So the current code I have now detects red cube matches properly but doesn't register more than 4 cubes. So if a row has 5 red cubes it doesn't register it as a match. But if the row has at least one non red cube it'll detect matches of up to 4 red cubes.
How can I get it to detect the  5 cube match in a single row?

@PlacidoPenitente good shout! You will also want to add another check after the for loop is done whether the current match contains enough elements - this will cover the case that the entire for loop only catches a single match and the last element is contained in that match

How do I do that?

@PlacidoPenitente I had already updated the code example ;) Just have a final if(currentMatch.Count >= 3) check after the for loop before you return the matches

I think you can use Physics2D.RaycastAll to emit a ray from top to bottom and detect any type of cubes. The returned array is also arranged in order from top to bottom. If you only want to detect how many stacked blue cubes are on the top, you just need to check each cube one by one and count until there is a red cube. Something like this:
var hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, rayDirection, Mathf.Infinity, cubeLayer);
int count = 0;
for( ; count < hits.Length; count++)
{
    if(hits[count].collider.Tag != "Blue")
        break;
}
    

